# Structure database in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backend

how can I make app for restaurant and need to create separated database for each restaurant , beside that I need to create another database that contain all customers only from all restaurant

this will be the structure

```
restaurants --->
----restaurant-1
----restaurant-2
----restaurant-3

customers --->  all customers in restaurant-1, restaurant-2, restaurant-3
```

I also need to make user in any restaurant separated from others so he can have one account and it contains 2 restaurant

Comment: I would do exactly that, but you should include the restaurant ID in the customer object. It could be a string or an array. You should think what queries you would normally run...and don't create unbounded arrays

Comment: Hard to answer this Q by StackOverflow (Too broad + based on opinion). Sometimes it is a good idea to separate your DB. Anyway, Create a separate DB for each restaurant sound like "mega overkill" (Easier to manage the front/backend/API of one collection of restaurants VS 500). Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916903/mongodb-performance-having-multiple-databases